# Iptables forward port traffic to another port with byte calculation

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, iptables-redirect

#### Problem

I want to `'redirect'` traffic from one port to another. But I need to be able to calculate how much `INPUT` AND `OUTPUT` bytes were used in communicating through that port.

#### Half Solution

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 50000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3478
```

This solution redirects all traffic from `50000` to `3478` everything here is fine, but I can't calculate how much `INPUT & OUTPUT` went through `50000` port! That is a crucial problem.

#### Current Setup

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=50000/udp;
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 50000;
iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --sport 50000;
```

I use this setup to calculate how much `INPUT` AND `OUTPUT` data was used, but this works only for specific port that isn't `'redirected'`.

#### Flow?

```
Packet -> 50000(adds bytes to INPUT) -> 3478;
Packet <- 50000(adds bytes to OUTPUT) <- 3478
```

If there is a better way of doing this than `iptables` I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following:

```bsh
# Tag UDP packets of the "connection" with mark 50000
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 50000 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 50000

# Make the port redirection
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 50000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3478

# Count the bytes with mark 50000
iptables -m connmark -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 3478 --mark 50000
```

`iptables -t mangle -nvL` will then show:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    4   132 CONNMARK   udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:50000 CONNMARK set 0xc350
...
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2    66            udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            connmark match  0xc350 udp spt:3478
```

Explanations:

- When using `-j REDIRECT`, you can't make a rule that will match an outgoing packet from port 50000, because all the outgoing packets of a connection on port 50000 will match `--sport 3478` but not `--sport 50000`, even though the actual packet will show a UDP source port of 50000 on a network capture. I don't know if this is a bug or an expected behavior (tested with iptables 1.8.2 (nf_tables))
- To workaround this, we can use the [`CONNMARK` target](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCR) that marks all packets of a connection with an arbitrary 32-bit integer on the PREROUTING side, then match the same mark with the [connmark module](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAN) on the OUTPUT side.